# Using System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter ExecuteNonQuery(); Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm working on a C# program that needs to use both an SQL Server Connection and a Local Data Base, I can easily retrieve data from both data bases with ExecuteReader(); which means the connection is being performed successfully.

But when I try to use ExecuteNonQuery(); It just throws a System.InvalidOperationException when dealing with the Local Data Base, with no additional info. It works fine when connecting to the SQL Server

Here's the function I'm having trouble with:

```
public String myFunction(String TLV, String SPName, String BD)
    {
        if (mdbEnabled.Checked == true)
        {
            string connectionString = string.Format("Provider={0}; Data Source={1}; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type={2}",
            "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0", BD, 5);
            using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand SP = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
                    SP.Connection = conn;
                    SP.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SP.CommandText = SPName;
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter IN_ERC = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter();
                    IN_ERC.ParameterName = "@IN_ERC"; IN_ERC.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32; IN_ERC.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output; IN_ERC.Value = 0;
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter CH_ASM = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter();
                    CH_ASM.ParameterName = "@CH_ASM"; CH_ASM.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String; CH_ASM.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output; CH_ASM.Value = 0; CH_ASM.Size = 1000;
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter IN_ASM = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter();
                    IN_ASM.ParameterName = "@IN_ASM"; IN_ASM.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32; IN_ASM.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output; IN_ASM.Value = 0;
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter CH_DSM = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter();
                    CH_DSM.ParameterName = "@CH_DSM"; CH_DSM.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String; CH_DSM.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; CH_DSM.Value = TLV;
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter IN_DSM = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter();
                    IN_DSM.ParameterName = "@IN_DSM"; IN_DSM.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32; IN_DSM.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; IN_DSM.Value = 0;
                    SP.Parameters.Add(IN_ERC);
                    SP.Parameters.Add(CH_ASM);
                    SP.Parameters.Add(IN_ASM);
                    SP.Parameters.Add(CH_DSM);
                    SP.Parameters.Add(IN_DSM);
                    try
                    {
                        SP.ExecuteNonQuery();//this always fails
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("error en SP.ExecuteNonQuery();");
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("IN_ERC: " + SP.Parameters["@IN_ERC"].Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("CH_ASM: " + SP.Parameters["@CH_ASM"].Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("IN_ASM: " + SP.Parameters["@IN_ASM"].Value);

                    return SP.Parameters["@CH_ASM"].Value.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(BD))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand SP = new SqlCommand();
                    SP.Connection = conn;
                    SP.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SP.CommandText = SPName;
                    SqlParameter IN_ERC = new SqlParameter();
                    IN_ERC.ParameterName = "@IN_ERC"; IN_ERC.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int; IN_ERC.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output; IN_ERC.Value = 0;
                    SqlParameter CH_ASM = new SqlParameter();
                    CH_ASM.ParameterName = "@CH_ASM"; CH_ASM.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar; CH_ASM.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output; CH_ASM.Value = 0; CH_ASM.Size = 1000;
                    SqlParameter IN_ASM = new SqlParameter();
                    IN_ASM.ParameterName = "@IN_ASM"; IN_ASM.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int; IN_ASM.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output; IN_ASM.Value = 0;
                    SqlParameter CH_DSM = new SqlParameter();
                    CH_DSM.ParameterName = "@CH_DSM"; CH_DSM.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar; CH_DSM.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; CH_DSM.Value = TLV;
                    SqlParameter IN_DSM = new SqlParameter();
                    IN_DSM.ParameterName = "@IN_DSM"; IN_DSM.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int; IN_DSM.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; IN_DSM.Value = 0;
                    SP.Parameters.Add(IN_ERC);
                    SP.Parameters.Add(CH_ASM);
                    SP.Parameters.Add(IN_ASM);
                    SP.Parameters.Add(CH_DSM);
                    SP.Parameters.Add(IN_DSM);
                    try
                    {
                        SP.ExecuteNonQuery();//this always works
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("error en SP.ExecuteNonQuery();");
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("IN_ERC: " + SP.Parameters["@IN_ERC"].Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("CH_ASM: " + SP.Parameters["@CH_ASM"].Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("IN_ASM: " + SP.Parameters["@IN_ASM"].Value);

                    return SP.Parameters["@CH_ASM"].Value.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I call the function with the following parameters:

```
someString = myFunction(OPN_ASM, "OPN_ASM", BD);
```

the BD variable is set depending on the mdbEnabled.Checked property value, it could either be:

`C:\Users\Angcrad\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\myDB.mdb`

if mdbEnabled.Checked==true

or

`Data Source=ANGCRAD\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True`

if mdbEnabled.Checked==false

The "myDB.mdb" file was exported from the myDB Data Base on the SQL Server, so both Data Bases have the same elements. Hope you can help me tracking down the error, thanks in advance

Comment: check here on this site for how to configure connection strings for `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB` it appears that that connection string in general at first glance is incorrect [C# Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the connection string is not the issue, as it works fine when calling ExecuteReader();

Comment: I would suggest using the debugger then and step through the code if that's the case..

Comment: Thank you.

Apparently, the SQL DB uses Stored Procedures which I think were not exported to the MDB file, I'm lookin into it right now

Comment: Normaly, ExecuteNonQuery is used   for update/delete/insert ,ExecuteReader for select.